# Where does M64Plus FZ store screenshots?

Tags: emulation, m64plus-fz

Where does the Android version of [M64Plus FZ](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mupen64plusae.v3.fzurita&pcampaignid=web_share) store screenshots?

[image: Saving a screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, screenshots were saved to *Internal Storage > Pictures > mupen64plus*.